# How to rename a dynamic block in terraform

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-ingress, hcl

I'm trying to use a dynamic block in a `kubernetes_ingress` resource. The dynamic block is for the `spec.rule.http.path` block. Unfortunately, I am trying to dynamically create a `path` block which causes issues as `path` appears to be a reserved word.

Is it possible to rename the loop variable within the dynamic block, or to otherwise circumvent this issue?

This is my current code:

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress" "ingress" {
  metadata { ... }
  spec {
    tls { ... }
    rule {
      http {

        dynamic "path" {
          for_each = var.services

          content {
            path = path.value.path
            backend {
              service_name = path.value.name
              service_port = path.value.port
            }
          }
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `services` variable has the following structure:

```
[
  {
    name: "foo",
    port: 3000,
    path: "/foo",
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Dynamic blocks take an argument called `iterator` that lets you rename the symbol it assigns values to.

```
dynamic "path" {
    for_each = var.services
    iterator = "service"
    content {
        path = service.value.path
        backend {
            service_name = service.value.name
            service_port = service.value.port
        }
    }
}
```